# JavaScript flatten array: are the two approaches the same in terms of the time complexity?

Tags: javascript, big-o

I am aware that an array method `flat` exists. but I would like to get a better understanding on how `...` and `concat` affect the time complexity.

```js
function flat1(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(
    (flatArr, item) => {
      flatArr.push(...(Array.isArray(item) ? flat1(item) : [item]))
      return flatArr
    },
    []
  )
}

function flat2(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(
      (flatArr, item) => {
        return flatArr.concat(Array.isArray(item) ? flat2(item) : item)
      },
      []
    )
  }
```

My intuition is that both approaches take O(n^2) time complexity worse case, `n` being the number of item in the original array. Because both `concat` and `...` are going to iterate through the array and it is going to take `n` for both operation. Is my understanding right?

Is one approach preferred over the other approach?

Comment: Have you considered Array.prototype.flatMap?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky can you give me an exapmle?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I mean I know what it is but I am not sure what you were suggesting here exactly.

Comment: I was suggesting a built in method to do flattening and mapping an array so you don't have to make your own. If you prefer to make your own, then perhaps update the question to indicate you don't want to use something like Array.prototype.flat + Array.prototype.map or Array.prototype.flatMap. It looks like you already mentioned that in the question, so you can probably ignore this then. The "preferred approach" would be to use flatMap btw.

Comment: The ellipsis method should be O(n). It can pre-allocate the result array at once by getting the total lengths of all the inputs, then copy them into place. The reduce method will be O(n^2) because it's allocating and concatenating one array at a time.

Comment: Your `flat1` should call `flat1`, and your `flat2` should call `flat2` I guess?

Comment: @Bergi yea you are right. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: I'm not sure if JS is a good choice for a processing task of the size where this difference starts to really matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will need to simplify the problem by not flattening recursively, but only a single level:

```
function flat1(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((flatArr, item) => {
    flatArr.push(...(Array.isArray(item) ? item : [item]))
    return flatArr
  }, [])
}

function flat2(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((flatArr, item) => {
    return flatArr.concat(Array.isArray(item) ? item : [item])
  }, [])
}
```

Let's assume the number of elements in `arr` is `n`, and the average number of elements in each `item` array is `m`. (And `item`s that are not arrays count into that average as `1`).

> both `concat` and `...` are going to iterate through the array

Yes, they both need to iterate through the `item` given to them. But that is not the point. `push` does *modify* the `flatArr` and takes `O(m)` time to add `O(m)` new elements onto it.

However, `concat` does create a new array, and for that it does not need to only iterate `item` but also `flatArr`. Given `flatArr` contains on average `O(n/2*m)` items, the `flatArr.concat(item)` takes `O(n/2*m + m)` = `O(n*m)`.

Since each of these operations is executed once for each item in the `arr`, we get

- for `flat1` the time complexity `O(n*m)` and
- for `flat2` the time complexity `O(n*n*m)` which is worse.

The time complexities of the recursive functions are way more complicated since they also depend on how many arrays you have on which nesting levels. I'm failing to even come up with a good metric to describe such data structure :-)